# Beginner Web dev: What may be the issue with float not working properly in webpage

Tags: html, css, frontend, css-float

Edited:

I am trying to have one of the section below float left and the other section float right. Both comes with image, paragraph, and a list of items. Before i apply float, they stack on top of each other. when i apply the properties, nothing change.

I tried to debug the code and found that the float property only works after i comment out the paragraph.
What may be a potential issue?

HTML & CSS Code Below:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

header,
.primary-content,
.secondary-content,
footer,
.introduction {
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
}

.secondary-content img {
  width: 20vw;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.secondary-content .parking p,
.secondary-content .tents p {
  margin-right: 50%;
}

.parking {
  float: left;
}

.tents {
  float: right;
}

footer {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
   <div class="secondary-content">
        <section class="parking">
            <img src="img/mtn-landscape.jpg" alt="image of a 
              mountain">
            <h3>Park Accordingly</h3>
          <!--  <p>One of the most important things when it comes 
                   to traveling through the great outdoors is 
                   packing accordingly. Here is a few tips:</p>
            --><ol>
                <li>Bring layers of clothing</li>
                <li>Pack sunscreen</li>
                <li>Carry extra water just in case</li>
                <li>Pack light</li>
            </ol>
        </section>
        <section class="tents">
            <img src="img/resort.jpg" alt="image of a resort">
            <h3>From Tents to Resorts</h3>
          <!--  <p>Lake Tahoe is full of wonderful places to 
                stay. You have the abillity to sleep in the 
                outdoors in a tent, or relax like a king at a 
                five star resort. Here is our top three resorts:
            </p> -->
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Lake Tahoe Resort Hotel</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">South Lake Tahoe Resorts</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Tahoe Ski Resort Lodging</a></li>
            </ul>
        </section>
    </div>
```

Comment: change `<section>` or `</section>` to `<div>` or `</div>`

Comment: It looks fine from the code you provided. Is there any borders or padding added to section elsewhere ?

Comment: add position: relative; to parent element.

Comment: Your snippet seems to work OK. Could you add whatever is needed of the other things you mention to make it not work?

Comment: change <section> does not work, add position does not work